# DB where between two date columns

Tags: mysql, date, laravel

I want to retrieve records between two date columns, in Laravel 42.

`Model::where('created_at', '<=', 'created_at' + 5 days)->get();`

I have a `created_at` column. I need to retrieve all records that are between `created_at` and `created_at` + 5 days.

I use this method to add days `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '+5 days'));` which works. But I cannot make it do what I want.

Is it possible at least? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's sense in that? It returns all the rows, so rephrase the question.

Comment: I need to retrieve all records that are between a `created_at` and `(created_at + 5 days)` date column.

Comment: No, you don't. Say what you want to achieve, not what you want to get from the db, because obviously not this.

Comment: @jarek - do not want to be rude, but he clearly said what does he want to achieve. He needs to extract the rows from the db between the condition, which means between the date of created row until 5 days only. Some sort of extracting the recent results not older than 5 days

Comment: @aspirinemaga You're not rude, just don't read the question. Unless OP wants to compare another column, which is not mentioned anywhere, or this query doesn't make any sense: `where created_at between created_at and created_at + interval 5 days`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do raw SQL then you need `DB::raw()`.

However, depending on whether I understand your issue correctly, the following may work for you:

```
$now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
$inFiveDays = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(5);
Model::where('created_at', '>', $now)->where('created_at', '<=', $inFiveDays)->get();
```

Doing that with `DB::raw()` and using raw SQL:

```
Model::whereRaw('created_at BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY');
```

Something like that, anyway.

Comment: That is not really what I wanted. With your code I retrieve all records that are between NOW and NOW+5 days. What I need is to retrieve all records between CREATED_AT and CREATED_AT+5 days. Very different things. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you tried out to change 'now()' to your created_a?

Comment: @Alexxali yeah I didn't think I'd read your question right - the problem is that what you're saying makes no sense to me: "all records between `CREATED_AT` and `CREATED_AT`+5 days" - what does that mean? What is `CREATED_AT`? If it's a field in the table (which therefore varies per row), how can you get all things that are between it and something else when it varies per row? That's what's really confused me here. Normally a query says get me all-things where something-that-varies-per-thing is something-constant, but you're wanting where something-that-varies is something-that-also-varies.

Comment: The query you have in your answer, assuming `CREATED_AT` is a date column in the database, is basically saying get me everythgin where the CREATED_AT column is less then its existing value + 5 days, which will obviously get you everything. A bit like doing `if (4 < 7) { /* code */ }` - it's redundant. But I really don't know what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any way to do it with SQL, so I found this solution:

```
$posts      = Posts::all();

foreach ( $posts as $key => $post )
    if ( strtotime($post->created_at . '+5 days') < time() )
        unset( $posts[$key] );
```

What I do here is that I iterate through the entire array of objects. As soon as I found a record that does not fit my time limits, I delete it from the array.

Comment: So rephrase your question. The query for this would be: `where created_at >= now() - interval 5 day`